# 2 regular graph on 5 vertices graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

what is the amount of possibilities to draw a 2 regular graph on 5 vertices. And how can I calculate that?

Thanks

Comment: Simple or with multiple edges allowed?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Two-RegularGraph.html - only show a cycle on 5 vertices.

Comment: Simple amount of edges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple two-regular graph is the disjoint union of cycles, each of which has at least three vertices. As $5<3+3$, you can have only one cycle of length $5$. A cycle on $n$ vertices is given by one of $n!$ permutation of the vertices (i.e., the order in which we run throuigh the cycle), but this counts each cycle repeatedly, on the one hand because we picked one of $n$ starting vertices, on the other because we picked one of $2$ possible orientations. Hence,
$$\frac{5!}{2\cdot 5} $$